# Where can I find my Vimeo Access Token Secret?

Tags: wordpress, vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm using a [WordPress Vimeo plugin](http://codecanyon.net/item/video-gallery-wordpress-plugin-w-youtube-vimeo-/157782) that requires an "Access Token Secret" in order to retrieve videos. In my Vimeo Developers App section (https://developer.vimeo.com), I only see the following:

- Client ID
- Client Secret
- Request Token URL
- Authorize URL
- Access Token URL
- Your Callback URLs
- Your unauthenticated authorization header
- Access Token
- Scope
- Your unauthenticated authorization header

There is no "Access Token Secret". Where can I find this?

Answer (score 0):

The API was recently updated, and the docs for the old API have been buried. The plugin you are using must have used the old API.

You can contact vimeo at vimeo.com/help/contact to ask for access to the old API, or look for plugins that use the new API. I know Vimeography uses the new API, and I'm trying to track down more.

I'll contact the wordpress plugin and see if I can work out a solution with them.

Comment: Thank you, @Dashron. Well, I've already paid for this plugin so I'm hoping that a solution can be found. I've contacted the author of the plugin and let him know about this as well.